# not writing http response properly

Tags: java, web

I'm using Spring MVC to create a webapp which has a button which when you press it, it hits a servlet outside my web application and returns an excel spreadsheet.

I am using a servlet to servlet style link between the applications rather than a direct link. I'm having a bit of an issue with the http header though. What is happening is that between the time I grab the file from the other application and the time that it is returned to the user in my application the file is getting corrupted. I think it's because I'm not writing the http header properly. I'm thinking this because the file is fine when I hit the other application outside of my application.

What I am trying to achieve is some code to make the http header in my application look exactly like the http header my servlet receives from the other application with the exception of the file name.

Here is my code.

```
private void getReportContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws BusinessException, ParseException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    int statusCode = 0;
    HttpState state = null;

synchronized (session) {
    state = (HttpState) session.getAttribute(HTTP_STATE_KEY);
    if (state == null) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("Creating new http state.");
        state = createHttpState(request);
        session.setAttribute(HTTP_STATE_KEY, state);
    }
}
String reportURL = null;
GetMethod getMethod = null;

try {

    // Generate the Report URL
    reportURL = createReportURL(request, response);                 
    getMethod = new GetMethod(reportURL);   
    getMethod.setFollowRedirects(false);

    // Retrieve the Report          
    statusCode = client.executeMethod(client.getHostConfiguration(), getMethod, state);
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("Status code from Reports servlet: " + statusCode);
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        throw new BusinessException(new Exception("No Report content found. Received HTTP status code " + getMethod.getStatusCode()));
    }

    response.setHeader("Date", getMethod.getResponseHeader("Date").getValue());
    response.setHeader("Server", getMethod.getResponseHeader("Server").getValue());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", getMethod.getResponseHeader("Content-Length").getValue());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", getMethod.getResponseHeader("Content-Length").getValue());
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", getMethod.getResponseHeader("Content-Type").getValue()); 
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + REP_REPORT_NAME + "\"");
    //Set the response into HttpServletResponse
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(getMethod.getResponseBody());            

} catch (IOException e){
    logger.error("Unable to contact report URL", e);
    throw new BusinessException("Unable to contact report URL",e);
} finally {
    // Close the HTTPClient connection
    if (getMethod!= null){
        getMethod.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or can anyone suggest any tips to achieve what I want to do. In the debug session when I have a look at the header returned from the other application it looks like...

```
[Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2013 10:47:42 GMT 
, Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g/9.0.4.1.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server 
, Content-Length: 802570 
, Content-Disposition: attachement; name="TestEmployeeReport.xls"
, Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "file is getting corrupted"? Do you receive any error?

Comment: First thing is to check where the file gets corrupted, checked it between your webapp and the servlet?

Comment: It gets corrupted after i return it from my webapp.  By corruption I mean that when I open the file it tells me that it can't read the rows in the spreadsheet because the format of the file does not match the file type

Comment: The exact error when I try to open in excel in "The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.